# Faulty if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

```
public void decompressTo(String fileName) throws IOException {

    for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.size(); i++) {
        if (fileArray.get(i) == new Character((char) 7)) {
            //do stuff
    }
    else {
        //do other stuff
    }
}
```

The problem is that my `if` statement is never being executed, instead, the `for` loop always jumps to the `else` statement.

However, the `fileArray` ArrayList that I am reading from **for sure** contains the bell character (ASCII Character #7). I have declared `fileArray` as follows: `ArrayList <Character> fileArray = new ArrayList <Character> ();`.

Comment: Try to print the size of the fileArray, before the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating `new Character((char) 7))` seems unnecessary object creation. Hence

Try this. Make suere your `fileArray.get(i)` is not null.

```
if (fileArray.get(i).charValue() == '7')
```

Answer (score 5):

== is reference equality in java (a check to see if two references reference the same object, rather than two equal ones). Use `fileArray.get(i).equals(...)` instead.

Comment: You can't compare two instances of the primitive type `char` with `.equals()`.

Comment: but you are comparing Character

Comment: @user1744094 I'm not sure whether you think that `Character`s are `char`s or whether you're just implying I should leave a note on the behavior of `==` on primitive types in general.

Comment: @user1744094 you can retrieve char Value and check with '7' check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your statement:

```
if (fileArray.get(i) == new Character((char) 7))
```

will be always `false` as `==` checks for same objects.

Try this instead:

```
if (fileArray.get(i).equals( new Character((char) 7)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If that is the whole method then you are missing a curly bracket. Also make sure you use equals when comparing strings, otherwise you are checking it bitwise and not by string content.

```
public void decompressTo(String fileName) throws IOException {

    for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.size(); i++) {
        if (fileArray.get(i).equals(new Character((char) 7))) {
            //do stuff
        } else {
            //do other stuff
        }
    }
}
```